# Is it possible to replace a string in a text file with a line break via the windows command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, text-files, line-breaks

I have a [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file) that contains a bunch of data on a single line without any [line-breaks](/questions/tagged/line-breaks). It will contain data that looks similar to this:

```
{"Id":1801157,":"33611134":"E","Oct 19:":"G","Order":"117" ,"BroadcastDate":"2019-10-19"}
```

What I want to do is insert a line break right before `BroadcastDate` so it now looks like this:

```
{"Id":1801157,":"33611134":"E","Oct 19:":"G","Order":"117" ,"
BroadcastDate":"2019-10-19"}
```

I want to be able to do it via a the [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line). So basically I want do to find `BroadcastDate` and replace it with `<line break>BroadcastDate`.

Comment: 1 line only in the file?  1 instance only of BroadcastDate?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an odd thing to do, but not very difficult in PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, it will have PowerShell.

=== Format-BroadcastFile.ps1

```
Get-Content -Path '.\BroadcastDate.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace 'BroadcastDate'."`nBroadcastDate"
    }
```

=== Run it in a .bat file script or the cmd shell.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "Format-BroadcastFile.ps1" >".\newfile.txt
```

Comment: `"\`n"` is the "syntax" for a newline in PS? Ouch! ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is an odd thing what I'm doing... but the end result is to place the date "2019-10-19" into a variable. Adding the line break was to isolate the BroadcastDate section to it's own line, so i can then use FINSTR and FOR loops to extract "2019-10-19". Unless you think there's an easier way

Comment: It sounds like you have not given us all of the story. Is any of the other information on the line need to be captured and associated with the date? Is there ALWAYS a single ISO formatted date on the line? I think there is a better way, but please put the end goal into the question.

Comment: Yes, the end result would be to take that YYYY-MM-DD date and store it into a variable in the batch file. The only way I've ever been able to capture specific data from a text file was to use FINDSTR to look for specific strings and save results to a second text file. Then use FOR loops to clean up the results and extract the target data to a variable.

Comment: FINDSTR can only return the entire line that contains the keyword and because the source text file is basically one big single line, the results that FINDSTR returns is basically the same as the source file. This is why I wanted to move BroadcastDate to a new line... to help isolate the target date data.